# Install .net 4.6.2 with Wix 3.10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix, windows-installer, .net-4.6.2

The [documentation for WixNetfxExtension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html) extensions says .Net Framework 4.6.2 web setup is supported.

I have the reference to WixNetfxExtension:

[image]

Why I am getting `error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'ChainPackageGroup:NetFx462Web'` trying to compile the bundle?

BTW, when I change to `NetFx46Web` it compiles OK, with `NetFx461Web` it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET 4.6.2 support was [added to WiX v3.11](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx462.wxs); it's not in WiX v3.10.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I download WiX 3.11? It’s not on the web site: http://wixtoolset.org/releases/

Comment: Could you please look at my answer to this question? My experience with WiX and MSI is minimal. Did I make it right, or am I screwed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, after about 6 months, that next version of WiX is released. Better late than never :-) Marking this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, .NET 4.6.2 ain’t supported by any stable version of WiX. And authors say weekly builds are **not** considered to be production-ready.

So, I did following.

1. I removed the reference to WixNetfxExtension.
2. Instead, I’ve added the reference to WixUtilExtension.
3. Then I’ve added two source files to my project I took from the latest WiX repository, `NetFx4.5.wxs` and `NetFx462.wxs`.

I've tested my installer on Win7 SP1 (which BTW is the minimum windows version that supports 4.6.2) virtual machine without .NET, it downloaded and installed .NET from the web just fine.

Comment: That works. WiX v3.11 is reasonably safe for production use; it's had a limited number of changes compared to WiX v3.10.3.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution? Why did you add WixUtilExtension, and what did you do exactly with the NetFx*.wxs files?

Comment: @jv42 WixUtilExtension is used by both NetFx4.5.wxs and NetFx462.wxs source files, see xmlns:util=http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension.

I’ve added those two .wxs files to my project, build action = compile.

Comment: Oh that simple? Great! Thanks for the quick answer.